# URL Rewriting in joomla site

Tags: url, joomla2.5, rewriting

I have enabled SEF in the site configuration and my urls are human readable. I have a menu structure as below
Channel -> Main channel items -> sub channels

for e.g I have a menu
Channel -> recipes -> poultry

In the poultry i have got many recipes for e.g grilled-chicken-with-cream-sauce when i am opening this item (its a k2 item) i am getting below mentioned url
http://www.kayftv.com/poultry/grilled-chicken-with-cream-sauce

What i want is i wanted to add **recipes** in the url just like below

http://www.kayftv.com/recipes/poultry/grilled-chicken-with-cream-sauce

Can you please suggest how would i achieve this

I am using joomla 2.5

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One answer is sub-menus.  So you would have a top level menu item of Recipes with alias recipes, add sub-menu item of Poultry with alias of poultry which displays the article in question.  This will generate the SEF url you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3295190/brian-bolli) can work well, and I've used it many times mysel.

One downside though is if you have a lot of articles, it will require plenty of leg work to get a clean URL without a prepended article id in the address.

Another option is to use a a [SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef) extension. [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) is one very good choice and there are others.

With sh404SEF, the general solution to your question would be to create **recipies** and **poultry** categories, configure sf404SEF and set it to manage your SEO.

I think the larger your site is, the more you want to look towards using a SEF extension. They can save you a lot of time, and make it much easier to make bulk, site wide changes.

Good luck!